# How many init methods in a game?

Tags: java, image, applet, initialization

Can there be more than one `init( )` method in one game applet? If not, how to load an image in every class file separately if the `init( )` method would just be in the main class?

Comment: No, init is once.Call the object of the main class, to other classes,for image loading.

Comment: *"how to load an image in every class file separately"*  Umm.. do it much the same way you might do it in `init()`.  How many images are there?  What do they show?  What are they used for (e.g. BG, textures, player pieces..)?

Comment: You can have as many `init()` methods as you wish. Only one will be called when your applet starts, though.

Comment: @AndrewThompson about 5 images? They show a boat, two palm trees, a gold treasure and mines ... the boat is a player piece and the mines are for collision detection.

Comment: @joeyrohan where shall I place the part of attaching the image's url? which should be in the `init()` method ... shall I place it the `paint()` method?

Comment: What is the problem with init method?I am not getting what you want.May be an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) will help.